# Unresolved attribute reference 'setModel' for class 'Dialog'

Tags: python, pycharm, pyqt5

Trying to create a dialog class which will contain a QTableView widget, all is good, information gets inserted, but i cannot understand why pycharm show the error: "Unresolved attribute reference 'setModel' for class 'Dialog'"

all class code here:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QTableView
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi


class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__()
        loadUi("dialog.ui", self)
        self.table = self.findChild(QTableView, "tableView")

    def fill_table(self, data):
        column_names = ["full_name", "mail", "age", "phone_number"]
        model = QStandardItemModel(1, 4)
        model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(column_names)

        for col_idx in range(4):
            item = QStandardItem(data[col_idx])
            model.setItem(0, col_idx, item)

        self.table.setModel(model)
```

explain me what's going on and suggest solutions to the problem.

Comment: Is it the pycharm inspector that shows the error, or do you actually get the error when running your program? If it's just the first, you can ignore it. The inspector isn't always smart enough to understand the code.

Comment: that's right, it's just the pycharm inspector, otherwise the program works correctly, but I'm a perfectionist, so I wanted to figure out if I'm really doing something wrong or if it's just a false mistake

Comment: PyCharm cannot sort out things generated dynamically, which is what happens by using `uic.loadUi` (which parses an XML file and creates widgets at runtime), so that's a false positive. You can safely ignore such *warnings* (remember that warnings and errors are quite different), but there should be ways to configure PyCharm to specifically ignore them, when using uic functions. Note that using `findChild()` is unnecessary, since the table is already accessible with `self.tableView`.

Comment: @musicamante, thanks a lot for explaining and more information!

Answer (score 0):

You can use type hints to make sure that pycharm knows the type of dynamically created objects:

```
class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__()
        loadUi("dialog.ui", self)
        self.table: QTableView = self.findChild(QTableView, "tableView")
```

or without the unecessary `findChild`

```
class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__()
        loadUi("dialog.ui", self)
        self.tableView: QTableView
```